# Getting ID in the first column on Autocomplete in the second Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using KendoGrid.I have four Columns out of which the First Column is input text and second column is AutoComplete i want to fill the ID of the Data that is being selected in Auto Complete in the First Column i.e in Input type text and then save it on server side by using loop.
Here is my code :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Invoice.Models.ViewModels.Setup.HeaderkViewModel>()
    .Name("HeadGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.HeadGRIDID).ClientTemplate("#= HeadGRIDID#" + "<input type='text' name='HeadGRIDID' class='HeadGRIDID' />");

        columns.Bound(p => p.AccountTransactionItemHead).Title("Head").EditorTemplateName("HeadAutoComplete").ClientTemplate("#= AccountTransactionItemHead#" + "<input type='hidden' class='AccountTransactionItemHead'  value='#=AccountTransactionItemHead#' />");
        columns.Bound(p => p.AccountTransactionItemDescription).Title("Description").Width(140).ClientTemplate("#= AccountTransactionItemDescription#" + "<input type='hidden' class='AccountTransactionItemDescription'  value='#=AccountTransactionItemDescription#' />");


    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create();
        toolbar.Save();
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.HeaderID))
        .Create("Editing_Create", "Grid")
        .Read("Editing_Read", "Grid")
        .Update("Editing_Update", "Grid")

    )
    )
My EditorTemplate Code is as Follows:
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AccountSelect(e) {
        var DataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        $("#HeadGRIDID").val(DataItem.HeaderID);
    }
</script>


@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                  .Name("AccountTransactionItemHead")
          .DataTextField("AccountTransactionItemHead")
          .Filter("contains")
          .MinLength(3)
            .Template("#=data.AccountTransactionItemHead#")
                .Events(events => events.Select("HeadGridSelect"))//need to write Script for CurrancySelect
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 240px;" })
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetHeadForHeadGrid", "Setup");
                  //.Data("onAdditionalData");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          })
)
```

here on change of the AutoComplete I have written the Script that fetches the Id of the particular data but i am not able to fill this Id in the Kendogrid as a First Column of the Grid.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old questions but maybe someone else has a similar problem:

This will work:

```
function AccountSelect(e) {
    var DataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    DataItem .set("HeadGRIDID", DataItem.HeaderID);
}
```

Using set of a dataItem updates the dataItem (set's dirty flag of record in datasource) and updates the ui.